# When is it ok to use AJAX to access Firebase data?

Tags: ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question is as simple as it sounds.
 When is it OK to use AJAX rather than create a new Firebase() object when retrieving data?

---

I could do this (AJAX) or I could create a new Firebase Object, which is better?

```js
function get_User_Data(User_ID) {
    var gotUserData = $.Deferred();

    var userName, userLastCheckIn;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: DataLocation + '/USERS/' + User_ID + '.json',
        type: "GET",

        success: function(data) {
            if(data != null) {
                userData = data;
                // console.log(userData);
                userName = data['Username'];
                userLastCheckIn = data['CheckIn'];
            }
        },

    }).always(function () {
        userInfo = [userName, userLastCheckIn];
        gotUserData.resolve();
    });

    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        $.when(gotUserData).done(function () {
            def.resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

I also want to know if this is secure?

I know that All Firebase data is sent and recieved over SSL, but is AJAX also over SSL when done in this way?

Comment: "is AJAX also over SSL" yes, Firebase's Database, Hosting and Authentication services are only accessible over secure connections. But your question is really broad and there is no single good answer. There are good cases to use the Firebase REST API, but there is no single "when is it best?" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.ajax()` approach calls [Firebase's REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/) and retrieves a JSON object from there. This happens a single time.

Attaching a listener to that same location will start synchronizing the data from that location to the client:

```
var ref = new Firebase(DataLocation);
ref.child('USERS').child(User_ID).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

So initially you will get the same data, but then you will also be notified of any updates tot he data.

Note that this is just one of the changes. Most of these will become clear as you read the [Firebase guide for web developers](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/), which I highly recommend.